# Having issue with using bookmark links with url routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing, bookmarks, fragment-identifier

I have url routing setup on this site. I have a bookmark link in a nav that goes to a item in the home page like so:`<a href="/default.aspx#about">About</a>` . The problem is that, when someone entered the url incorrectly like `site.com/contact/`, instead of making the url `site.com/default.aspx#about`, it is making the url `site.com/contact/default.aspx#about`. All the other urls in the nav use the correct path. I know it has to do with the hashtag. Is there a way around it?

Comment: Can you show us how you make the bookmark?

Comment: @HanletEscaño, On the default page I add this `<a name="about" class="anchorTag"></a>` and on the nav i have this '<a href="/default.aspx#about">About</a>' .

Comment: @HanletEscaño . I figured out my issue. I was writing this url in the code behind and I was not adding the forward slash to all instances of that url. I am such an idiot. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having

```
<a href="/default.aspx#about">About</a>
```

Try this:

```
<a href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/default.aspx#about") %>'>About</a>
```

This should always write the correct URL regardless.